# How to correctly send argument to xargs to have it perfect intact

Tags: bash, arguments, space

This will be argument piped into xargs to bash:

```
$ ls
foo
'foo bar'
```

but fail to do it in such:

```
$ n=7; ls| xargs bash -c "for i ;{ echo -e $n \$i ;}" 0

7 foo 
7 foo
7 bar
```

instead of

```
7 foo
7 'foo bar'
```

How to do it the correct way ? Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, [don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```sh
printf '%s\n' * | xargs printf "$n %s\n"
```

If you have GNU `xargs`, a much more robust solution is to use null bytes instead of newlines as item separators:

```sh
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 printf "$n %s\n"
```

But of course, in this case, `printf` alone is quite sufficient.

```sh
printf "$n %s\n" *
```